# Scip integrate with mingw and msys

Tags: windows, msys, mingw32, scip

How can I integrate SCIP with MinGW and Msys?

Comment: How about closing this question, Mostofa?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you are waiting for a real answer, I can already guide you to this page from the official site on how to build SCIP (see below). For actual integration there is a pointer in the [faq](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/FAQ.php):

### How do I construct a problem instance in SCIP?

> First you have to create a SCIP object via SCIPcreate(), then you
>   start to build the problem via SCIPcreateProb(). Then you create
>   variables via SCIPcreateVar() and add them to the problem via
>   SCIPaddVar(). The same has to be done for the constraints. For
>   example, if you want to fill in the rows of a general MIP, you have to
>   call SCIPcreateConsLinear(), SCIPaddConsLinear() and additionally
>   SCIPreleaseCons() after finishing. If all variables and constraints
>   are present, you can initiate the solution process via SCIPsolve().
>   Make sure to also call SCIPreleaseVar() if you do not need the
>   variable pointer anymore. For an explanation of creating and releasing
>   objects, please see the doxygen documentation.
>
> **NOTE**: See the directories "examples/MIPsolver/" and "examples/Queens/" for simple examples

### Remarks on Building/Installing under Windows using MinGW (from http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/INSTALL.php)

> To build your own Windows binaries under Windows, we recommend using
>   the MinGW-Compiler with MSYS from mingw.org
>
> First install MSYS, then MinGW to the mingw folder inside the msys
>   folder. Now you need to install the following packages to the mingw
>   folder:
>   - zlib (or use ZLIB=false ZIMPL=false since zlib is needed for ZIMPL and ZIMPL-support in SCIP)
>   - pcre (or use ZIMPL=false since pcre is needed for ZIMPL and ZIMPL-support in SCIP)
>   - gmplib (or use ZIMPL=false since gmplib is needed for ZIMPL and ZIMPL-support in SCIP)
>
> (After calling "make clean" in the ZIMPL folder you will also need
>   flex and bison to remake ZIMPL.  We recommend NOT to use "make clean"
>   inside the ZIMPL-folder if you do not have these packages installed.)
>
> You can download these additional packages as precompiled binaries for
>   example from: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html
>   (zlib&pcre) http://cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/ (gmplib) or compile the
>   source on your own from the project homepages: http://www.zlib.net/
>   http://www.pcre.org/ http://www.gmplib.org/ (The command "./configure
>   --prefix=/mingw ; make ; make install" should succeed without problems and installs the packages into the mingw folder.)
>
> Now "make READLINE=false" should be compiling without errors. Please
>   note that we do NOT support creating the doxygen documentation or
>   readline-usage under Windows.
>
> Since there are no real symlinks in MSYS, the include and library
>   files of SoPlex and ZIMPL are actually copied into the
>   SCIP-lib-folder. When you recompile ZIMPL or SoPlex after compiling
>   SCIP you have to copy the libraries manually into the SCIP-lib-folder
>   and recompile SCIP afterwards.